# How to use wordpress shortcode in template

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I need help with wordpress shortcode. I have written shortcode function in functions.php in my theme files. Now I create page in wordpress administration and then I need to place this shortcode into special place in my theme but with content which I wrote in administration.

I hope that you understand what I mean.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: this should be as simple as checking the API..  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

Comment: I know what you mean but if I use do_shortcode function in theme the problem is that there is no display content from page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your template code:

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[your-shortcode]'); ?>`

Replace `[your-shortcode]` with whatever your shortcode is, including parameters/attributes and/or closing tags if required.

Comment: I know this code but If use this code there is not content which I insert into shortcode in wordpress administration.

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make much sense, so I suspect you do not understand the function of shortcodes in content (via admin panel) versus hard coded in a template file.

Comment: Yeas it is true that I do not understand this function. I try to explain what I need to do. I need to have some editable content in administration which I need to show in my theme. I thought that the best way how to do it is with shortcode. So I did shortcode in function.php then use this shortcode in page (in administration) and now I need to show this shortcode on specific place.

Comment: @folpy Custom Fields / Post Meta may be more helpful in your situation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields (also check out the plugin Advanced Custom Fields).

Comment: Oh I forget that in wordpress exist custom fields. I think that this is best way how to solve my problem. Thank you for your help.